# Mount ISO contained in Docker to host volume

Tags: mount, docker, iso

Is there any way to mount an ISO contained in a Docker so that the contents of the ISO are available to the host machine?

I can do this on a Linux host by using a bind mount with `shared` as the bind propagation setting and then mounting to the shared folder within the Docker.

**Starting container:**

```
docker run -v /mnt/myiso:/mnt/myiso:shared --privileged mydocker
```

**Inside container:**

```
mount myimage.iso /mnt/myiso
```

Unfortunately `shared` bind propagation is only available on Linux hosts. I would like this to work on macOS and Windows hosts as well.

I thought perhaps an NFS share would enable it but I haven't been able to get that to work (the NFS volume is always mounted with `slave` propagation within the container).

Comment: Do you need `--privileged`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I believe you can use more fine-grained access rights than `--privileged` to enable a docker to mount an ISO but I can trust the docker image so I'm not too concerned.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a docker container with an iso file inside. Build a multi stage docker image doing iso content extraction in a folder at first stage, and copy the contents to a predefined host volume at last stage in the entrypoint.

Comment: @ChaoxiangN the ISO is not available at docker build time (it's on a shared drive mounted by the docker) and the contents of the ISO would take too long to extract. It needs to be mounted so the host has random access.